# (C++) declaration of 'std::string fil' shadows a parameter

Tags: c++, string, compiler-construction

I am trying to make my own compiler(yes) and c++(cpp version of cc) is giving me an error saying: error: declaration of 'std::string fil' shadows a parameter.

Code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

int compile(std::string fil)
{
    std::string cmd = "cc ", fil; // error here
    system(cmd);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   if (argc == 2) {
       std::string tmp = argv[1];
       compile(tmp);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `std::string cmd = "cc ", fil;`?

Comment: I'm trying to add the parameter fil to cmd.

Comment: What is your question?  Yes indeed, you are attempting to create two `std::string`s in the same scope, both named `fil`.  (The previous one is the function's parameter).

Comment: So you want to tcombine `"cc "` with whatever is in the `fil` parameter?

Comment: If that's the case, you want `std::string cmd = "cc " + fil;`, not `std::string cmd = "cc ", fil;`

Comment: @coolCguy `std::string cmd = "cc ", fil; // error here` -- I'm wondering what made you write the code this way.  The usage of `+` to join two `std::string`s is one of the most common things that is done in C++, so common that it's hard to get it wrong.  Using a comma is one of the most creative "wrong" ways I've seen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not Sure what is your question - but compiler is correct:

```
<source>:7:30: error: redefinition of 'fil'
    std::string cmd = "cc ", fil; // error here
                             ^
<source>:5:25: note: previous definition is here
int compile(std::string fil)
```

You have a redefinition of parameter. You should rename one of them.

to add strings

```cpp
    std::string cmd = "cc " + fil; // error here
```

Comment: But where is the redefinition? Can't find it.

Comment: ```std::string cmd = "cc ", fil;``` is equal to ```std::string cmd = "cc"; std::string fil;``` I think you don't understand what comma operator does in this case. You do not concatenate 2 string in that way in c++

Comment: @mpatro Note the `,` in this case is actually not a comma operator in this case, it's more of a punctuator to separate a init-declarator-list.